# jQuery events and double firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I load jQuery dynamically with AJAX, elements with existing events fire multiple times.

Basically I have one file called 'myjs.js' which hold All my jQuery and is included when the page is loaded therefore setting up events and such for elements.

Now when a user triggers an event like posting a new comment, it sends off (via Ajax) the comment, then it returns a page with the new comment, edit comment, reply etc. Obviously when `myjs.js` was first loaded it didn't create any events for the newly loaded elements. Therefore I include `myjs.js` in the page returned with AJAX.

As the `myjs.js` has already been loaded with the page, when the Ajax page is returned with `myjs.js` included, it adds another event to the elements that have already been loaded with the page.

I have already tried

```
$('*').unbind();
```

But this caused some strange effects.

So any ideas on loading jQuery dynamically while not affecting any events which already exist for elements?

Comment: look into `.on()` if you are on 1.7 or greater or `.delegate()` if below 1.7

Comment: Use the `live` or `delegate` method to bind event listeners for future (AJAX-generated?) elements (or `on` for jQuery 1.7+). See also: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look into delegating events, so that events work on new elements as well without injecting JavaScript.

Comment: UserB, this is not a code issue. Thanks PeeHaa and Rob, I'll look into these, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the jQuery code, I suspect that the selectors being used to bind behaviour are too generic so as you have discovered, all existing elements plus the newly loaded elements are matched each time:

You could use more specific binding in the JavaScript returned in the AJAX response to add behaviour *only* to the newly loaded elements.

However, returning the same JavaScript for each AJAX request is inefficient as the browser cannot cache. Ideally you should try and load the JavaScript on the main page once and then rely on jQuery to do [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binding automatically for the newly loaded elements. This is also known as event delegation - [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Note that as of jQuery 1.7 these methods have been deprecated in favour of a more concise event binding infrastructure - the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Note: please avoid `.live()` and use `.delegate()`. It's (much) better performance wise.

Comment: Noted, thanks very much for all your help. Manged to sort it out in 10 letters. I ended up using `.on`

Comment: Happy to help and glad you can use 1.7. The event binding is much simpler and nicer from that version